# Workarund missing Union support in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I wonder if there is any better solution to my Problem.

I have a Service1 that handles two different input types (A|B) using method overloading.
A Service2 should provide a method that accepts all input types of Service1 and does some work with the result, which I do not want to duplicate.

I came up with two solutions, but neither of those is convincing to me.

```kotlin
data class A(...)
data class B(...)
class C

class Service1 {
  fun doSomething(input: A): C {}
  fun doSomething(input: B): C {}
}


// Solution 1
class Service2_v1 {
  private val service: Service1

  fun <T>doThings(input: T) {
    val result = when(input) {
      is A -> service.doSomething(input)
      is B -> service.doSomething(input)
      else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
    }

    ...work with result
  }
}

// Solution2
class Service2_v2 {
  private val service: Service1

  fun doThings(input: A) = handleResult(service.doSomething(input))
  fun doThings(input: B) = handleResult(service.doSomething(input))

  private fun handleResult(result: C) {
    ...work with result
  }
}
```

Since this only needs to work with Types that are known at compile type, I wonder if there is a cleaner solution with generics, similar to this pseudo code:

```kotlin
class Service2_notWorking {
  private val service: Service1

  fun <T : ArgumentTypeOf<Service1.doSometing>>doThings(input: T) {
    val result = service.doSomething(input)

    ...work with result
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the "inline" and "reified" keywords, and how they are used by some Kotlin stdlib functions for example.

Comment: I did so, but could not find any solution.